# How to do ErrorHandling using catchError RxJS Operator in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, rxjs, observable

I'm new to Angular/Typescript and using catchError RxJs. I'm also using .subscribe and pipe operators. I would like to use observable as much as possible, combining it with RxJS operators. On submission of my form, frontend calls the API and a new product gets created and would like to have proper error handling for Error Codes of 400 and 500 using HttpErrorResponse.
I wrote below code but not sure if I'm doing the error handling correctly as I get the below error (see bottom).

app.component.ts

```
onSubmit(): void {
    if (this.form.valid) {
        console.log('Creating product:', this.form.value);
        this.http.post('/api/create', {
            productName: this.form.value.productName,
        }).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status == 500 || err.status == 502 || err.status == 503) {
                this.err = "Server Side Error";
                return throwError(err);;
            }
            else if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status == 400){
                this.err = "Bad Request";
                return throwError(err);;
            } else if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status == 422){
                this.err = "Unprocessable Entity - Invalid Parameters";
                return throwError(err);;
            }
        })
          .subscribe(
            resp => this.onSubmitSuccess(resp), err => this.onSubmitFailure(err)
        );
    }
    this.formSubmitAttempt = true;
}

private onSubmitSuccess(resp) {
    console.log('HTTP response', resp);
    this.productID = resp.projectID;
    this.submitSuccess = true;
    this.submitFailed = false;
}

private onSubmitFailure(err) {
    console.log('HTTP Error', err);
    this.submitFailed = true;
    this.submitSuccess = false;
}
```

**Errors:**

app.component.ts - error TS2339: Property 'err' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

app.component.ts:124:16 - error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction'.}).subscribe(

Answer (score 3):

To solve your issue, I have modified the code and shown below.

```js
onSubmit(): void {
  if (this.form.valid) {
    console.log('Creating product:', this.form.value);
    this.http.post('/api/create', {
      productName: this.form.value.productName,
    }).pipe(catchError(errorResponse => {

      const err = <HttpErrorResponse>errorResponse;

      if (err && err.status === 422) {
        this.err = "Unprocessable Entity - Invalid Parameters";
        return throwError(err);
      } else if (err && err.status === 400) {
        this.err = "Bad Request";
        return throwError(err);;
      } else if (err && err.status === 404) {
        this.err = "Not found";
        return throwError(err);;
      } else if (
        err &&
        (err.status < 200 || err.status <= 300 || err.status >= 500)
      ) {
        this.err = "Server Side Error";
        return throwError(err);;
      }
    })
    .subscribe(
      resp => this.onSubmitSuccess(resp), err => this.onSubmitFailure(err)
    );
  }
  this.formSubmitAttempt = true;
}
```

I would suggest creating a common exception service that handles any exception. You should separate the outgoing API calls to a separate service and then use that in your component. It will be easy to read and maintain the code. Try the below code logic.

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ExceptionService {
  constructor(private toastService: ToastService) {}

  catchBadResponse: (errorResponse: any) => Observable<any> = (
    errorResponse: any
  ) => {
    let res = <HttpErrorResponse>errorResponse;
    let err = res;
    let emsg = err
      ? err.error
        ? err.error
        : JSON.stringify(err)
      : res.statusText || 'unknown error';
    console.log(`Error - Bad Response - ${emsg}`);
    return of(false);
  };
}
```

In your service, you can create a post method like this

```
saveEntity(entityToSave: EntityToSave) {
  return <Observable<EntityToSave>>(
    this.http.post(`${postURL}`, entityToSave).pipe(
      map((res: any) => <EntityToSave>res),
      catchError(this.exceptionService.catchBadResponse),
      finalize(() => console.log('done'))
    )
  );
}
```

From your component, call the service which handles the exception

```
this.yourService.saveEntity(entityToSave).subscribe(s => {
  // do your work... this get called when the post call was successful
});
```

I hope it solve your issue.